# Wordress Utimate Member plugin - None of the page contents display with no errors

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm not very familiar with PHP. I have installed Wordpress 5.4 and Ultimate Member 2.1.5.

I wanted to display the members page. So, I have created the page and pasted the shortcode([ultimatemember form_id="196"]) that is generated from the Member Directories. On going to the member page I don't see any content. It's completely empty with no errors.

Did I missed anything or the plugin is not supported for this wordpress version?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you're understanding correctly how to add shortcodes. Generally, you'll just paste `[ultimate_member form_id="196"]` in the post or page editor and update or publish. That's it.

If you're adding to a template or function file (php file), then you'll be adding some variation on `<?php echo do_shortcode( '[ultimate_member form_id="196"]' ) ; ?>` as in the fuller example shown here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/#comment-2379

If you're doing one or the other of the above, and things aren't working, then you may have a more complicated issue.

Comment: I have added the shortcode correctly. The reason I have put in the brackets is just to show what I have added. Eg. - <?php echo do_shortcode( '[ultimate_member form_id="196"]' ) ; ?>

Comment: Well - if you're setting it right, but not getting any output, then you might want to review the instructions and put a question in the plugin support forum. According to the listing, 2.1.5 is the latest version, dated this month, and tested up to 5.4 https://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-member/#developers